# What sequence should I start with to calculate the cohomology of $\mathbb RP^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I want the simplest way to learn how to calculate the cohomology of $\mathbb RP^n$ with $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients, please?

What sequence should I start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the simplest way is to use the CW decomposition of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with one cell in each dimension, resulting in the cellular chain complex as in Example 2.42 in Hatcher:
$$
\dots \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \to 0
$$
The right hand end of this is dimension $0$. The left hand end is unspecified because it depends on whether $n$ is even or odd: the first map is either $\times 0$ or $\times 2$ depending on the parity of $n$.

Hatcher explains the maps being multiplication by 0 or 2. Briefly and informally, you can think of this cell structure as coming from the cell structure on $S^n$ with two cells in each dimension, an upper and lower hemisphere in each dimension $k \leq n$. The map $S^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$ identifies these pairs of hemispheres. You can compute the maps on the cellular chain complex for $S^n$ using the geometry of $S^n$, and then apply the quotient map to get the chain complex for $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

Apply $\mathrm{Hom}(-, R)$ for any coefficient ring $R$ to get the corresponding cochain complex, from which it is easy to compute $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n; R)$.

Comment: how do we get the $\mathbb Z$'s in the cellular chain complex ( I believe the one you are writing is for n even)?

Comment: How did you get the multiplication by $2$ and the zeros maps?

Comment: This is the chain complex for any $n$; the left-hand end of it varies depending on $n$, but the right-hand end of if is the same regardless (in dimensions $0$, $1$, ...). The $\mathbb{Z}$'s in the chain complex arise because, as I said, there is one cell in each dimension, and the cellular chain complex in dimension $k$ is free abelian with basis given by the $k$-cells. One $k$-cell leads to a single copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Edited to add some details about $\times 2$ and $\times 0$ maps.

Comment: How about the computations with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients instead of $\mathbb Z,$ how it differs?

Comment: The computation with any coefficients is already part of my answer: let $R=\mathbb{F}_2$ (assuming you mean the field with 2 elements). Of course the $\times 2$ map becomes zero, mod 2.